# How to use happy.js to validate integer?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page which has an input of integer.
I find happy.js a lightweight form validation, so I want to try it.

Comment: An integer: `/^[+-]?[0-9]+$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say, you have

```
<input id="integer" type="text" name="integer" />
```

You could do

```
function is_integer(value) { return value.test(/^[+-]?[0-9]+$/) }

// Your "validation scheme", as per happyjs.com...
...
'#integer': {
  required: true,
  message: 'This must be an integer',
  test: is_integer // this can be *any* function that returns true or false
},
...
```

Did you try reading http://happyjs.com/?